# How to remove the top border of an embedded SVG element

Tags: html, svg

This is a part of my HTML I have embedded the SVG element.

```
<div>
<embed id="svgsource" type="image/svg+xml" src="/CXF/2012-01-27---11-35-47/6.svg">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="900px" height="751px" onload="init()" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
</embed>
</div>
```

But when you go to this page, you notice a visible line on top of the SVG element, as if it has set a top border:
[image: Picture of the html]

is there any way to get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have an inline <svg> element inside the <embed>? Have you tried removing that part?

Maybe the svg you reference has a rectangle to serve as a border? In that case you'll need to change the `"/CXF/2012-01-27---11-35-47/6.svg"` file itself.